# Projection of skew lines on plane of common perpendicular

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

Suppose $L_1$ and $L_2$ are two skew lines in the $\mathbb{R}^3$. Draw the common perpendicular line of them $L_3$. The plane $P$ is parallel to the $L_3$. What is the relative position of orthogonal projection of $L_1$ and $L_2$ on the plane $P$? I think the answer is parallel but I can't prove it. I'm looking for an analytic answer to this problem.

Comment: There are a lot of planes parallel to $L_3$. Did you mean perpendicular?

Comment: @stevengregory The question hasn't mentioned any other conditions for $P$ .

Comment: Choose coordinates such that $L_1$ is the $x$-axis and $L_3$ is the $z$-axis.

Comment: @Aretino In that case the answer is a point which isn't a general result .

Comment: The result isn't necessarily a point: there are many possible planes $P$.

Comment: @Aretino Can you show it using analytic geometry ?

Comment: It suffices to observe that the planes perpendicular to $P$, and passing through $L_1$ and $L_2$, are parallel between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let consider

- $v_1$ direction vector of $L_1$
- $v_2$ direction vector of $L_2$

then

- $v_3=v_1\times v_2$ is such that $v_3$ is a direction vector of $L_3$.

Let consider $P: ax+by+cz=0$ then $n=(a,b,c)$ is such that $n\cdot v_3=0$ then $n \in$ plane spanned by $v_1$ and $v_2$.

Now consider the ortogonal basis $\{n,v_3,n\times v_3\}$ therefore in that basis for some coefficients $a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2$ we have

- $v_1=a_1n+b_1(n\times v_3)$
- $v_2=a_2n+b_2(n\times v_3)$

therefore the orthogonal projection of $L_1$ and $L_2$ onto $P$ have direction vectors parallel to $n\times v_3$ and then they are parallel.

[image]